# 70d Wifi password reset

Tags: canon

I have had my 70d for about 2 months. I had the wifi function set up and it was working fine. This past weekend it asked for me to re-enter my password. I have no idea why I used as my password. How do I go about retrieving of resetting it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just set again the WiFi password as it is described in to the [documentation](http://kbsupport.cusa.canon.com/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1011&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=false&TIMEZONE_OFFSET&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=61654)

Of course this will ask for password on other devices you use to connect to camera via WiFi